# Django form submission error: 'GameArticleComment matching query does not exist' - any solutions?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, templatetags

am getting an error when trying to submit an form for blog comments
please anyone to help me and direct me where l went wrong.

The error is **GameArticleComment matching query does not exist.**
even l tried **get_object_or_404** but l still get the same error.

Even I a added some pictures showing the source of error, below.

[image: image showing the top view of the page error]

[image: image showing the source of the error]

below is my code:

**views.py**

```
def article_detail(request, uid):
    data = get_object_or_404( GameArticle, slug=uid,  status='p')
    comments = GameArticleComment.objects.filter(article= get_object_or_404(GameArticle, slug=uid), parent=None)
    replies=GameArticleComment.objects.filter(article=get_object_or_404(GameArticle, slug=uid)).exclude(parent=None)
    replyDict={}
    for reply in replies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.sno]=[reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.sno] .append(reply)
    
    context={'data':data,'comments':comments, 'replyDict':replyDict }
    return render(request, 'Blog/article_details.html', context)


def Article_comment(request):
    url= request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment=request.POST.get("comment")
        user=request.user
        articlesno=request.POST.get("articlesno")
        article=GameArticle.objects.get(sno=articlesno)
        parentsno=request.POST.get("parentsno")
        if parentsno == " ":
            comment=GameArticleComment(comment=comment, user=user, article=article)
            messages.success(request, 'Your Comment Has been Published Successfully')
            comment.save()
            return redirect(url)
        else:
            parent=GameArticleComment.objects.get(sno=parentsno)
            comment=GameArticleComment(comment=comment, user=user, article=article, parent=parent)
            messages.success(request, 'Reply has been Added Successfully')
            comment.save()
            return redirect(url)    
    return redirect(url)
```

**models.py**

```
class GameArticleComment(models.Model):
    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment=models.TextField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article=models.ForeignKey(GameArticle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-timestamp']
```

**extras.py**

```
from django import template


register=template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_reply')

def get_reply(dict, key):
    return dict.get(key)
```

**article_detail.html**

```
{% load extras %}

<!--======= COMMENT FORM ====--->

     <form action="/articlecomment" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h4 class="fst-italic">Add a comment.... <small class="text-primary">({{ comments.count }})</small></h4>
            
          <textarea  id="textarea" name="comment" ></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="articlesno" value="{{data.sno}}" >
          
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mt-3 "> <i class="bi bi-send"></i> Send</button>
          </form>

<!---====== REPLY FORM ======--->

<form action="/articlecomment" method="post" style="padding: 0.5rem;">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <textarea name="comment" id="" class="border border-warning form-control  rip3 text-light bg-dark "  style="padding: 5px;"></textarea>
                  <input type="hidden" name="parentsno" value="{{ comment.sno }}" >

                  <center>
                    <input type="hidden" name="articlesno" value="{{data.sno}}" >

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3 bi bi-send">Send</button>
                </center>
                </form>

<!--====== REPLY LOOPING =====------->

{% for reply in replyDict|get_reply:comment.sno %}
          <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch comment-data col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="comment-user">
             <img src="{% static 'assets/img/team/team-1.jpg' %}" alt="" srcset="">
             <h6><small class="username text-warning">{{reply.user.username}}</small><small class="date text-muted">{{reply.timestamp|naturaltime}}</small></h6>
           <div class="comment-details mt-3 mb-3 text-muted">
             <small>{{reply.comment}}</small>
           </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           {% endfor %}

<!--========== COMMENT LOOPING =====-->
          {% for comment in comments %}
          <div class="comet mb-2">
            <img src="{% static 'assets/img/team/team-1.jpg' %}" alt="" srcset="">
            <strong>{{c.user.username }}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <small class="text-align-right h6 text-muted">{{comment.timestamp| naturaltime }}</small>
            <div class="content">
            <small class="toast-body ">{{ comment.comment }}</small>
          </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

At first I was able to send the comment but when l added The reply section, everything became worse, l don't know why